# Proving that $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\gamma_{1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)\zeta + 1}$ is equal to itself?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

In the text "Functions of a Complex Variable" I'm having trouble verifying if my proof of $(0.)$

$(0.)$

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\gamma_{1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\gamma_{2}}\frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)}$$

Remark:
$\gamma_{1}$ is $\partial{D(1,1)}$ with a clockwise orientation and where $\gamma_{2}$ is $\partial{D}(-1,1)$ equipped with a counterclockwise orientation.

Proposition(1.1):(Cauchy's Integral Formula)

Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic the unit disk ${D} = {\zeta : | \zeta - P | \leq r}$ is completely  contained in $U$. Let $\Gamma$ be the circle forming the boundary of ${D}$. Then for every a in the interior of ${D}$

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$

Applying Cauchy's Integral Formula to the RHS and LHS side of $(0.)$, one can make the following assertions:

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\Gamma_{1} = {|\zeta - (-1)| \leq 1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)}= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{1}=|\zeta - (-1)| \leq 1}\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta + 1}}{\zeta -1 }d \zeta = 2 \pi i \cdot f(1)$$

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\Gamma_{2} = {|\zeta - (-1)| \leq 1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)}= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{1}=|\zeta - (-1)| \leq 1}\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta + 1}}{\zeta -1 }d \zeta = 2 \pi i \cdot f(1)$$

Obviously accounting on the far RHS side of our previous observations it easy to notion that:

$$2 \pi i \cdot f(1) = 2 \pi i \cdot f(1)$$

Comment: Sorry but $\gamma_1=\gamma_2$? Another strange thing is that you seem to consider integrals on *disks*, which are simply undefined.

Comment: @upvoters Care to explain what the question is about?

Comment: Any operations involving Cauchy's Integral Formula involve it being a closed disk since that's how it's defined.

Comment: Not at all. Please check your notes, which should mention integrals along circles, say, but never on disks.

Comment: My mistake it would involve the unit disk

Comment: Wrong again. Are we going to see a meaningful question...

Comment: @Winther, I posted an answer but now you make me doubt it is correct, it doesn't seem that there is a problem with poles on the contour in how I wrote the integrals, but if there's a problem please point it out and I will delete my answer immediately

Comment: @Chris It's just me who is stupid. I misread the contours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: as Did says, it doesn't make sense to integrate on disks in the complex plane, you integrate on circles.
That being said, there are some errors in your last lines, they should read

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\Gamma_{1} = {|\zeta - (-1)| = 1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)}= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{1}=|\zeta - (-1)| =1}\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta - 1}}{\zeta -(-1) }d \zeta = \frac{1}{-1-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\Gamma_{2} = {|\zeta - 1| = 1}} \frac{d \zeta}{(\zeta - 1)(\zeta + 1)}= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{1}=|\zeta -1| = 1}\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta + 1}}{\zeta -1 }d \zeta =  \frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

And you should change the sign of the second integral because of the orientation. In the two cases the $a$ in Cauchy's formula is the center of the circle.

Note that the integration is done on the two *circles* which are the *boundaries* of the disks you were talking about (I changed the domain of integration in the integrals). If this is not clear to you I suggest you re read the chapters about integration in the complex plane in your textbook.

Comment: The ending should actually just be $f(1)$, not $2\pi if(1)$.

Comment: I should get more sleep